# Android gallery widget with out of memory issue

Tags: android, memory, gallery

I have a gallery widget with a about fitfy (almost) full screen images. Images are loaded from SD Card, and only one image is visible at a time (accept for overlap when scrolling). The problem is that after scrolling throught about 35 images I get OutOfMemoryError: bitmap exceeds VM budget. I thought a gallery widget disposed of views as required, but I guess I'm either mistaken or doing something wrong.

I use a CursorAdapter to load data, and I notice that whenever I scroll to new image, both newView() and bindView() is called. I would assume this means that the original view had been disposed of, but the out of memory issue seems to indicate the opposite. I'm using a ViewHolder with quite a few fields.

So my questions are:

1. Does a gallery widget behave differently than a listview when used with a CursorAdapter?
2. Is there a way to force recycling and/or desposing of views? (Or what could I be doing wrong).
3. Other suggestions for dealing with out of memory issues for this scenario? Downscaling is not really an option, and the gallery should be able to deal with unlimited number of images (or at least twice as many).

Comment: Are you holding a reference to Views somewhere else that would prevent them from being GCed?

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure not. I have tried stripping it down as much as possible. Any tips for gotchas? What would cause the convertView CursorAdapter.getView to be null? Since newView is called each time an item is made visible, convertView is null each time. I'm probably wrong, but I would assume that an item would either hold on to it's view or release it for GC. Furthermore, if I just scroll back and forth between the first 8-10 items, I never get an OutOfMemory (but still calls to newView() for every item).

Answer (score 0):

What's the image dimension? It will cause the problem. Try this to reduce the image dimension:

```
BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//Best to use powers of 2.
o2.inSampleSize=2;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
```

Comment: To reduce the image dimensions you actually need to increase the sample size.